# Raising a complex polynomial to the Kth power

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-theorem

While working with the following problem in complex analysis:
[image: page1]

I have $\varphi(z)=z+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n}z^n$ by considering $z_0=0$, i.e. a power series expansion centered around zero.
Now if I raise $\varphi^k(z)$ I get $z^k + O(z^{n+1})$, but I should get a linear term in z. What am I missing? For example, for k=2, I have $\varphi^2(z)=z^2+a_{n}z^{n+1}+....$.

I havve an auxillary question in this problem, why is $z_{0} = 0$?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $z_0=0$.  Your Taylor series should be expanding around $z_0$, so the powers are $(z-z_0)^n$.  The constant term is then $z_0$ and the first order term is $1\cdot (z-z_0)$, which combine to make $z$.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is the open unit disk and $z_0=0$ then this is immediate from Schwarz Lemma. Apply a suitable transformation to prove it in general.

Comment: See [Consequences of a fixed point of a bounded, complex analytic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798764/consequences-of-a-fixed-point-of-a-bounded-complex-analytic-function). Part (b) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your error seems to be that you computed the $k$-th *power* of $\varphi$. What you need is the $k$-th *iterate* of the function.

Comment: @MartinR - I have that $\varphi^k = \varphi \circ \varphi ... \circ \varphi$ -. Isn't this $\varphi^k$? i.e. $\varphi$ multiplied by itself k times. What did you mean by k-th  iterate?

Comment: @curious_analyst: $\circ$ is the composition, not multiplication. So $(\varphi \circ \varphi)(x) = \varphi(\varphi(x))$, $(\varphi \circ \varphi \circ \varphi)(x) = \varphi(\varphi(\varphi(x)))$, etc.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR. I see it now

Answer (score 2):

**Answer assuming $\Omega$ is simply connected**

To your auxiliary question, there’s no reason $z_0=0$, but it’s a smart idea to transform it into zero. Since $\Omega$ is bounded and open$^1$, the Riemann mapping theorem lets you find a conformal map $f:\mathbb D\to\Omega$. This map does not necessarily take $0$ to $x_0$, but by composing with a suitable automorphism of $\mathbb D$, this can be arranged. Define $g=f^{-1}\circ\phi\circ f:\mathbb D\to\mathbb D$ with $$g(0)=f^{-1}(\phi(f(0)))=f^{-1}(\phi(x_0))=f^{-1}(x_0)=0.$$ Thus $g$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Schwarz lemma. Moreover, iterating the chain rule twice, $$g’(0)=(f^{-1})’\circ\phi\circ f(0)\phi’\circ f(0)f’(0)=\frac{\phi’\circ f(0)f’(0)}{f’\circ f^{-1}\circ\phi\circ f(0)}=\frac{\phi’(x_0)f’(0)}{f’\circ f^{-1}\circ\phi(x_0)}=\cdots=1$$ where I’ve skipped some of the easy plugging in of numbers. The Schwarz Lemma tells us that $g$ is in the form $g(z)=\alpha z$ and in particular $\alpha=1$. Thus, returning to the definition of $g$, $\phi(z)=f\circ g\circ f^{-1}(z)=f\circ f^{-1}(z)=z$.

**Answer for general (connected) $\Omega$**

As suggested by Martin R, we use iterates of $\phi$ to solve the problem in general. By translating the problem, we may assume $z_0=0$ and we can write $$\phi(z)=z+az^m+O(z^{m+1}),$$ where the 0th order term vanishes because $\phi(0)=0$ by assumption. Here $z^m$ is the next nonzero term in the Taylor series, but of course it could be that there are none and $a=0$. We define the iterates of $\phi$ as the composition $\phi^k=\underbrace{\phi\circ\cdots\circ\phi}_k$. Moreover, since $\Omega$ is bounded, $\phi:\Omega\to\Omega$, and consequently $\phi^k:\Omega\to\Omega$, we see that $\phi^k$ must be bounded. Uniform boundedness of a holomorphic family implies it is a normal family by Montel’s theorem, so we conclude $\{\phi^k:k\geq0\}$ is normal.

Next we compute $\phi^k$. From the Taylor approximation above, you can see that $\phi=z+O(z^m)=O(z)$. Therefore $$\phi^2(z)=\phi\circ\phi(z)=(z+az^m+O(z^{m+1}))+a(z+O(z^m))^m+O(z^{m+1}).$$ Taking advantage of the $O(z^{m+1})$ error and using the binomial theorem, this implies $$\phi^2(z)=z+2az^m+O(z^{m+1}).$$ Repeating this, one finds that $$\phi^k(z)=z+kaz^m+O_k(z^{m+1}).$$ So we compute the $m$th derivative$^1$ of the $k$th iterate, $$(\phi^k)^{(m)}(0)=m!ka.$$ If $a\neq0$, these $m$th derivatives at $0$ are not bounded in the family, so no sequence within it can be converging to an analytic function, contradicting the normalness we showed. Therefore $a=0$ and so $\phi=z$ in a neighborhood of $0$, and therefore in the connected component of $\Omega$ containing $0$. (If $\Omega$ is disconnected, there is nothing stopping $\phi$ from having some other behavior on the other components.)

$^1$ Please note that by $O(z^m)$ we mean an expression of the form $z^mg(z)$ where $g(z)$ is analytic. This is stronger than the more common meaning of the notation but we need it to differentiate here.

Comment: I am not sure if it so easy for multiply connected domains, perhaps I am overlooking something simple. – There is an alternative approach considering the *iterates* (not powers) as a normal family, see my above link.

Comment: I haven't yet covered conformal maps - but Thank you.

Comment: @MartinR You’re right, I fixed it. It must be a bad argument to use more machinery and get a worse result.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that is now essentially the same argument as in part (b) in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3175172/42969  :)

Comment: Sorry to repeat your nice proof! For my own benefit (and completeness) I had to write it out.