# proving this function is bounded and limit

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open with $z_0 \in \Omega$. Also suppose that $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ is holomorphic with $f(z_0)=z_0$ and $|f'(z_0)|<1$.

Prove that there is a $r>0$ and $0<c<1$ such that $$|f(z) - f(z_0)|\leq c |z-z_0|$$ holds for all $z \in \Omega$ with $|z-z_0|<r$.

I thought about proving this by using the fact that $|f'(z_0)|<1$. But I'm stuck...

Secondly, suppose $\Omega$ is now bounded and connected. Prove that for all $z \in \Omega$ it holds that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(z) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(f(...f(z))) = z_0$ where $f_n = f \circ f_{n-1}$. And prove that this convergence is uniform on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

For this second point I have no clue how to start.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798764/42969 for the second question.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: for the first question use the definition of $$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = f'(z_0)$$
Since the modulus is continuous, you can show that
$$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{|f(z)-f(z_0)|}{|z-z_0|} = |f'(z_0)|$$
now write this using the $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition of limit and you will get the result.

For the second question, use induction to show that
$$0 \le |f_n(z) - f_n(z_0)| \le c^n |z-z_0|$$
Since $|c|<1$ you can use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: $|f_n(z) - f_n(z_0)| \le c^n |z-z_0|$ proves uniform convergence to $z_0$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$. It is a little bit more work to show that this holds throughout the entire domain.

Comment: @MartinR how would i do this?

Comment: @jacobthesecond: Did you see the link at your question? Are you familiar with normal families and Montel's theorem?

Comment: @MartinR I can't open the link. I am familiar with normal families and Montel

Comment: @jacobthesecond: Your question is part (a) of  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798764/42969